# SparseImage - Illegal Byte Sequence - HDID / Mac OS mounting

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

I have an sparseImage that was created on High sierra but when I was loading it for the first time on a new machine, lost power as it was mounting.  Now when I try to load it by double clicking the sparse image or using hdid with the terminal I get the error Illegal byte sequence.  I can't find anywhere how one would go about correcting the image.  Below is the output when running hdid with the -debug switch.

Thanks for any help you can provide.
Tom

The console output I have is to long to post, but ends with:

```
hdiutil: attach failed - Illegal byte sequence
```

Comment: You're more likely to get a response to a question like this on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com). Stack Overflow is geared toward programming questions.

Comment: That was where I started, but I thought it was a different entity.  Ill move to there.